# How to get rank of a matrix in Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, rank, eigen3

How to get [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix in [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

Comment: Build FullPivLU or ColPivHouseholderQR or whatever from the matrix, those have `rank()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert your matrix to a rank-revealing decomposition. For instance `FullPivLU`. If you have a `matrix3f` it looks like this :

```
FullPivLU<Matrix3f> lu_decomp(your_matrix);
auto rank = lu_decomp.rank();
```

**Edit**

Decomposing the matrix is the most common way to get the rank. Although, LU is not the most reliable way to achieve it for floating values as explained on the [rank article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computing_the_rank_of_a_matrix)

> When applied to floating point computations on computers, basic
>   Gaussian elimination (LU decomposition) can be unreliable, and a
>   rank-revealing decomposition should be used instead. An effective
>   alternative is the singular value decomposition (SVD), but there are
>   other less expensive choices, such as QR decomposition with pivoting
>   (so-called rank-revealing QR factorization), which are still more
>   numerically robust than Gaussian elimination. Numerical determination
>   of rank requires a criterion for deciding when a value, such as a
>   singular value from the SVD, should be treated as zero, a practical
>   choice which depends on both the matrix and the application.

So you might get more accurate results with `Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR< MatrixType >`

Comment: does computing decomposition  performance is better than computing rank itself? ( and why eigen used decomposition?)

Answer (score 2):

use QR or SVD decomposition and check the resulted matrix should also work. SVD may be more reliable.