# How to exactly compute rank of binary matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix of 0's and 1's, and wish to compute its rank. One [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31042188/543913) is to compute an approximate decomposition and return a count of the number of pivots that exceed some small threshold.

Though this will usually equal the rank for a reasonably chosen threshold, the two definitions are not mathematically equivalent. What is the best way to compute according to the mathematical definition of rank?

Comment: Simple method: Use Gaussian elimination, make use of the fact that for boolean values, addition corresponds to XOR, and in the end count the number of nonzero rows.